# Recylerview scroll is not working . i'm using cardview

Tags: android, material-design

It's been a week, I am working on Recyclerview. I need help below is my code. 
Activity.java

```
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);
    final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    layoutManager.scrollToPosition(2);
    layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(2, 20);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.getLayoutManager().canScrollVertically();
```

Activity.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:scrollbarSize="5dp"
    />
```

Any Help will appreciated.Thank You!

Comment: I tested your code and it is working perfectly. It doesn't scroll at all?? Or is getting stuck???

Comment: Yup.I have tried everything. And your are correct it is stuck somewhere. I'll figure out. Thank you for help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use like this in a simple way.

```
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

In xml part,

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible">
```

Comment: still, it is not working. And I am not using fragment . Thank you for your help :)

Comment: make sure that any of your parent view is not a scrollView

Comment: Nope , I'm using linear layout as a parent view .

Comment: If your code is not related to some private thing, can you share your code on github?

Comment: Sorry it's private , I'm developing app for client .So I can't share it.